# Issue with an adding padding to the left and right of the navbar using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I have a problem with padding on navbar with Bootstrap because I am not able to add padding right and left to menu items like "Home" "Features" etc, but when I do padding-top and bottom it works?

anyone can check code and see why padding left and right to menu items doesn't have any effect, but if you add padding-top and bottom it works?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-orange">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

***CSS Code is Below***

```
.navbar{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
.navbar-brand{
    margin-left: 34px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
    'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.bg-orange{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.navbar-nav{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 
    'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.nav-item{
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 22px 0px 22px 0px;
}
.nav-item:hover{
    background: orange;
}
```

**UPDATE: FIXED IT:**
Changed class of "nav-item nav-link" to "nav-item"

Comment: Add your full-working code to your question, or even use [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) to share it with us, so that we can help you! :)

Comment: Can you put the code how you are adding the padding to those elements? Just tried to add `padding` and it is working fine

Comment: done did it :) .

Comment: It works fine, here's a [live preview](https://codepen.io/elharony/pen/BvQvwa). If you've changed the padding, it would work just fine!

Comment: @Elharony yes but if you try to add padding-left and right to menu items it doesn't work.

Comment: @behar Remember, there are 2 classes for each menu's item. The `nav-item` and `nav-link`, by default: `Bootstrap` apply `padding-right: .5rem; padding-left: .5rem;` to the `.nav-link`... You need to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's css has `padding-right: 0;` declared on nav-link in `_navbar.scss`.

You can either

1. include your css file after bootstrap's on the page, or
2. use `!important` to make your style declaration take precedence.

Also, I think you have your css padding declaration mixed up. It works for me with 1 small change:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NebeMN

Simply change `padding: 22px 0 22px 0;` to `padding: 0 22px 0 22px;`

The order is: top, right, bottom, left. See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp. (FYI - This can be shortened to `padding: 0 22px;`)

So finally you end up with `padding: 0 22px !important;`. However, I would recommend using option 1 above rather than using !important.

Comment: still doesn't work for me.
.nav-item{
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 0 82px 0 82px;
}
changed padding from 22 to 82 and padding on left and right in items doesn't change even if you add 182px or 882px or even more?

Comment: yep it worked, but isn't there any way to fix this without !important ?
Because with !important some other styles could be overridden

Answer (score 0):

**So the answer to your question because it is using bootstrap's padding:**

[image]

---

**1. You need to rewrite it with `!important` tag.**

`padding: top, right, bottom, left !important;`

The code above is just to show what values go where.

---

**2. Another solution is to add new class**

`.item{ padding-right:22px !imporant; }`

and add this class to elements that you want to override and don't affect other elements with bootstrap's class.

Comment: isn't there any way without !important to use because I do not want to override other styles with !important ?

Comment: @behar You should link to your css file on your page after bootstrap's css.

Comment: @Kev is right, you are loading your css before bootstrap

Comment: you talking about stylesheet link on html or how ? i didn't get it correctly sorry

Comment: @behar updated the answer. He is talking about html where you link css files. You are linking your css first before bootstrap.

Comment: @AntihypeBird I have bootstrap css file linked first see image below mate
http://prntscr.com/lx2350

Comment: nevermind it worked:
Changed class of <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
to <a class="nav-item" href="#">Features</a>

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work?

```css
    .navbar{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 4px solid black;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .navbar a{
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-toggler {
        margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-brand{
        margin-left: 34px;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
        'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .bg-orange{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
        'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .nav-item{
        transition: 0.3s;
        padding: 32px 20px 22px 0;
        margin: 5px 0 0 40px;
    }
    .nav-item:hover{
        background: orange;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-orange">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: tried but still only top and bottom showing, not padding left or right having any change

Answer (score 0):

It is the *specificity* of your selector.

The default bootstrap styles for `.nav-link` are:

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link { ...
```

Your selector is just:

```
.nav-link { ...
```

As you can see, the bootstrap one is more specific. You need to be *more specific* (without using !important!)

Seeing as you have an `id` on your `.navbar-collapse`, you could do:

```
#navbarNavAltMarkup a.nav-link { ...
```

That is using an `ID`, ID's are more specific than classes.